# Laravel 8 Cannot Disable Logging even I deleted the config in Production

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have searched everywhere and do anything that suggested, even i deleted the logging.php in config folder, but still laravel creating laravel.log which is anoying for me.
i set in my .env file

```
LOG_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=null
```

but still no luck. How to completely disable this logging?

Comment: did you tried to turn APP_DEBUG=false or not in .env

Comment: yes, APP_DEBUG = false because in production i dont want expose any log

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the following lines in .env

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=false
LOG_CHANNEL=null
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=null
BROADCAST_DRIVER=null
```

and run the following commands

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

I hope it was useful !

Comment: if set broadcast to null, will my notification email being affected? because in my app there is functional to send email notification

Comment: no it will not .